# How to fetch all long-lived operations on iOS

Tags: swift, cloudkit

### Short summary

When I

1. create a long-lived CKModifyRecordsOperation on my iPhone while it is in airplane mode (no internet connection)
2. then quit the application that created the CKModifyRecordsOperation by double tapping the home button and swiping away the application
3. disable airplane mode and connect to the internet via a wifi network (still with the application quit)

I can see (in the CloudKit dashboard) that the operation was sent to the iCloud servers and executed properly.
But when I then reopen my app and call `fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDs(...)` on the same CKContainer, I get (**no** error and) a list of **0 operations**.

--> **How can I retreive the operation created in** (1.) **?**

---

### Detailed explanation

I am trying out CloudKit in a simple CRUD application ([source](https://github.com/Dev1an/Woordjes) can be found on GitHub). The application consists of a macOS app and a iOS app. The two applications share most of the CloudKit code.

The reference docs state that the array returned from the fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDs call is:

> An array containing the identifiers for all the active long-lived
>   operations. If a long-lived operation is canceled or completed, it is
>   no longer an active operation, and its identifier will not be included
>   in this array.
>
> An operation is complete if the app successfully
>   receives the completion callback.

When I add a long-lived operation like this (while not connected to the internet):

```
let deletion = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: [someRecordID])  
deletion.isLongLived = true  
deletion.start()
```

*this code can be found [here](https://github.com/Dev1an/Woordjes/blob/c2eee7c6c67f38869bd9370e0341450e1ded06dc/Woordjes/CloudWords.swift#L142) in my sample application on github*

And then quit my app, connect to the internet and reopen my app, the following fetch: [(GitHub link)](https://github.com/Dev1an/Woordjes/blob/c2eee7c6c67f38869bd9370e0341450e1ded06dc/Woordjes/CloudWords.swift#L198)

```
cloudContainer.fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDs { operationIDs, error in
  if let error = error {print(error)}
  print(operationIDs.count)
}
```

returns 0 operations and no error when I try it on my iPhone.

Like I said before, I also use the exact same code for a macOS app. And surprisinly, on macOS it does return 1 operation when I do the exact same things.

OK so I thought: maybe for some reason, in iOS the operation completes (which means: *the app successfully receives the completion callback*, as described in the documentation) while the app is not running (because I quit it myself). So I repeat this whole sequence (described in the summary) but I manually save the operationID, and then when I reopen the app, I fetch the operation by its ID with `fetchLongLivedOperation(withID: ..., completionHandler: ...)` to see if the operation was really completed in the background. But no, I get back my operation and it is still marked as active (or outstanding as it is written in its debugDescription) [(GitHub link)](https://github.com/Dev1an/Woordjes/blob/c2eee7c6c67f38869bd9370e0341450e1ded06dc/Woordjes/CloudWords.swift#L169).
So for some reason the operation is still active but I am not able to retreive it using `fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDs`.

Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

---

I'm using

- **macOS** 10.12 (16A323) on a MacBook Pro 15" (late 2013)
- **iOS** 10.0.1 on an iPhone 5

Comment: I'm running into the same issue ... `fetchLongLivedOperationWithID` works and returns an 'active' operation after the app is launched, but `fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDsWithCompletionHandler` shows an empty array. Did you ever resolve this? With reference to the answer below, the `longLivedOperationWasPersistedBlock` is definitely called, and I quit the app and kill the debugger after this.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at your code, it does not look like you set the `longLivedOperationWasPersistedBlock` on the long-lived CKOperations.

According to the [`longLivedOperationWasPersistedBlock` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckoperation/1452366-longlivedoperationwaspersistedbl):

> If your app exits before this block is called, the long-lived operation identifier is not included in the results of the `fetchAllLongLivedOperationIDs(completionHandler:)` method.

If you are force-quitting the app before the long-lived operation is persisted (which you currently don't check for - I'd suggest specifying that block and logging), that could indeed cause the issue.

Comment: So you are suggesting persisting only works if this block is implemented

Comment: @malhal no based on my experience the block is not mandatory unless you want to do something special. No harm in having it to print logs.