# upload offline changes on cloud with CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

CloudKit is the framework that powers iCloud on IOS 
I used this framework recently in a new project and i found it cool and easy to use 
but I had one issue and it's about offline mode 
when I have two devices A and B connected to the same ICloud account 
if A has no internet connection and made changes , how can I upload those changes to Cloud once A is connected to the Internet 
i looked too much about that and I found solutions like :

** using core data with cloud kit

** using framework called Sorix/CloudCore to handle this

** CKOperation with Long-Lived

about the first solution I think it's complicated to create coredata individually from cloud data and i read that it's recently kind of deprecated 
for the second solution it will be my last option because using 3rd party framework always has a cost and I'm not sure how it works
for the third option I don't know if it's working or not but i included because I found this question with no details

[How to fetch all long-lived operations on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133533/how-to-fetch-all-long-lived-operations-on-ios)

does anyone know how to handle offline operations ?
and it the 3rd solution is working , could you give a sample code for that
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can use Seam3 to link core data and cloudkit

Comment: Is it offline ?

Comment: It uses Core Data locally and syncs to CloudKit when available